# Use angular brackets in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, vb.net, label

In VB.NET Label,

```
lblNotification.Text = send email to <name@gmail.com> me
```

O/P I am getting as `send email to me` and it not displays the `<name@gmail.com>`. How to display the full text including angular brackets. That is, I need to get the O/P as `send email to <name@gmail.com> me`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Label1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("send email to <name@gmail.com> me")
End Sub
```

The [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) method will automatically convert your string to html encoded text

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`. So your text should be `send email to &lt;name@gmail.com&gt; me`

Comment: Normally if this is set inside the Text property of an ASP.NET label you don't need to do it. It should automatically HTML encode the text. I guess that the OP is not showing his actual code.

Comment: this property is set in code behind, not in the aspx markup.  That is why it is necessary to manually encode it

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Ignore my first comment. The text needs to be encoded.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's better to use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` for encoding. But I mentioned about `<` and `>` only and I guess it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the &lt and &gt like below

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNotification" Text="send email to 
&amp;lt;name@gmail.com&amp;gt me;" />
```